# Google Spread Sheet PHP API

Tags: php, google-sheets

i am working on write data in google sheet using php api,
but i see that data is big so continously api calls uses much api quata...
so i decided to update columns not rows.

any solutions for that?

code that i have...

```
$sheet_data = ['Link Name','Clock Url','All Clicks'];
$rows = [$sheet_data];

$valueRange = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues($rows);

$range = $sheet_name."!A1:A3";

$options = ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);
```

i can't update columns using this range.
anyone have solution then please update me.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.